# How would I handle sideways collisions in two dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision-detection

I've been experimenting with the html  element.
I'm trying to make a 2d sidescroller game and I've been having issues with collisions on the sides of objects.

Walking on the top of objects works just fine and hitting the bottom of objects also works but I cannot get colliding with the side of an object to work. I've made dozens of attempts which all end up introducing dozens of new bugs while also not fixing the problem.

Here's the code

```
<html>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px"></canvas>
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') { window.module = module; module = undefined; }</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>

<span id="x"></span>
<span id="y"></span>
<br>
<br>
<span id="test"></span>

<script>
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function clear() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    }
    let keys = {};
    $(document).keydown(function (e) { //Records keystrokes
        keys[e.which] = true;
    })
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        delete keys[e.which];
    });

    let worldx = 10;
    const x = 90;
    let y = 0;

    let yVel = 0;

    let grounded = false;

    let objects = { //I'm representing the game world as an array of boxes
        "boxes": [
            { "width": 50, "height": 10, "x": 45, "y": 100 },
            { "width": 75, "height": 20, "x": 60, "y": 150 },
            { "width": 10, "height": 100, "x": 125, "y": 40 }
        ]
    }

    let id = window.setInterval(function () { //Lock it at ~60fps
        clear();
        $("span").empty();
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 20) //Player character
        yVel += 9.8 * 0.016 // force of gravity
        y += yVel

        for (let check = 0; check != objects.boxes.length; check++) { //Loop through objects
            if (y >= objects.boxes[check].y - 20 && y <= objects.boxes[check].y + objects.boxes[check].height && x < objects.boxes[check].x + worldx + objects.boxes[check].width && x >= objects.boxes[check].x - 10 + worldx) { //Check if there is a collision.
                yVel = 0;

                //TODO add something here that will handle side-on collisions

                if (y <= objects.boxes[check].y + objects.boxes[check].height / 2) {
                    y = objects.boxes[check].y - 20
                    grounded = true
                }
                else {
                    y = objects.boxes[check].y + objects.boxes[check].height
                }
            }
            ctx.fillRect(objects.boxes[check].x + worldx, objects.boxes[check].y, objects.boxes[check].width, objects.boxes[check].height) // draw object

        }


        $("#x").append(Math.floor(x - worldx) + ", ")
        $("#y").append(Math.floor(y))

        for (i in keys) {
            if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) { continue; }
            if (i == 32 && grounded) { //Space bar
                yVel -= 5;
                grounded = false;
            }

            if (i == 65) { //A
                worldx += 3;
            }
            if (i == 68) { //D
                worldx -= 3;
            }
        }
    }, 16)
</script>

</html>
```

The TODO comment is where I check for collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good start for you(this code is from scratch, yours is a little tricky for me to understand):

```
var px = 0;//player's x and y
var py = 0;
var velX = 0;
var velY = 0;
var grounded = false;
var pw = 20;//player's width
var ph = 20;//player's height

var block = function(x, y, w, h) {
    if (px + pw > x && px < x + w && py + ph > y && py + ph < y + 5 && velY > 0) {//Top
    velY = 0;
    grounded = true;
    py = y - ph;
    }
    if (px + pw > x && px < x + w && py < y + h && py > y + h - 5 && velY < 0) {//bottom
    velY = 2;//bonk
    py = y + h;
    }
    if (px + pw > x && px < x + 5 && py + ph > y && py < y + h && velX > 0) {//left
    velX = 0;
    px = x - pw;
    }
    if (px > x + w - 5 && px < x + w && py + ph > y && py < y + h && velX < 0) {//right
    velX = 0;
    px = x + w;
    }
};
```